# Chrome Extension referencing/calling other script functions from a content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a content script with a lot of functions in it, i would like to be able to split out those functions into other scripts

Is there any magic needed to call other scripts from the content script

my manifest contains both scripts

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
      "*://*/*"
    ],
    "js": [
      "content.js",
      "other.js"
    ]
  }
]
```

my content script is working fine

however if i put a function in the other.js file and step through it, anything i reference in other.js is undefined

is there anything i should know here?

**Edit:**

This is just a simple example, the Test function should run on contentscript load

**contentscript.js**

```
Test();
```

**other.js;**

```
function Test(){
  return true;
}
```

Google is telling me uncaught ReferenceError, Test not defined

Comment: Post some code. How/What/Where do you call which function and what do you expect to see (but isn't there) ? (Did I mention you should be able to communicate between the scripts without any problem ?)

Comment: if the above edit should work, maybe there is a load order i'm not taking into consideration

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, it was the load order of the manifest

Comment: Changing the order is indeed one solution. See my answer below for a possible alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to add a little more for anyone looking for an answer regarding the other scripts, as well as other methods for extension script access.

You can access the rest of the extension's scripts using the [chrome.extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension) methods, as well as the [chrome.runtime](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime) communication methods.

1. To get an array of all of the scripts from an extension, you can use the [extension.getViews](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getViews) method.
2. You can also grab the background script, or a specific background script with the [getBackgroundPage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage) method.
3. Another option is to use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to pass the contents of a script with the [runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) method, and using an event listener on another script to listen for [runtime.onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) allowing the script to receive the data from the sending script.
4. In addition to the previous option, you can use also use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to receive scripts from another active extension sending with [runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage), but this time using an event listener with the [runtime.onMessageExternal](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessageExternal) instead (Cannot be used in Content Scripts).

I hope this helps someone, as much as it would have helped me earlier on.

Answer (score 13):

According to the docs on **[Content Scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)**:

> **js**: The list of JavaScript files to be injected into matching pages. These are injected in the order they appear in this array.

In your case, `content.js` would be injected first and try to execute `other`'s `Test()` function, before `other.js` is loaded).

Note that based on your manifest, both scripts will be loaded at "document_idle", so even if `content.js` has registered the call to `Test()` to be run after the page is loaded, it should still run immediately (since the page is already loaded.
If you want your scripts to be injected before the page's content is loaded, then modify your manifest:

```
"content_scripts": {
    ...
    "run_at": "document_start"
```